# UNION records from two tables and favor fields that are not NULL (otherwise favor values from first table)

Tags: mysql, union

I have fought my way through various answers and did some progress, however, the final solution has not been discovered.

The DB situation:

**Table "clients_a":**

```
userid | name 
1      | Steve
2      | John
3      | Paul
```

**Table "clients_b":**

```
userid | name 
1      | NULL
3      | Jokename
4      | Jessy
```

**Desired result/output:**

```
userid | name 
1      | Steve
2      | John
3      | Paul
4      | Jessy
```

Description of what is going on:

- `userid` is unique in the result (merged)
- a result for `name` that is not NULL is favored
- if two entries, then result from table `clients_a` is favored
- all entries have a groupid (see below), that has to be taken into account

MySql queries I tried (and came close):

**Attempt 1:** This query works, but it does not regard the name. It takes all names from `client_a`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT userid, name
    FROM `client_a`
    WHERE groupid = 123

    UNION DISTINCT 

    SELECT userid, name
    FROM `client_b`
    WHERE groupid = 123
) AS res
GROUP BY res.userid
```

**Attempt 2:** This query creates duplicate entries (one userid can occur twice), but regards the name, as it seems:

```
SELECT o.*, i.* FROM
(
    SELECT userid, name 
    FROM `client_a`
    WHERE groupid = 123

    UNION DISTINCT 

    SELECT userid, realname 
    FROM `client_b`
    WHERE groupid = 123
    
    GROUP BY userid
) AS o
LEFT JOIN `client_a` as i on i.userid = o.userid
```

I also tried to use `MIN(name)` without success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: "innodb_version 5.7.33"

Comment: Sidenote: I think I am going to solve this issue by PHP using two separate MySql queries. It looks simple but is probably complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.userid, a.name 
FROM clients_a a
WHERE a.groupid = 123
  AND (name IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM clients_b b WHERE b.userid = a.userid))
UNION  
SELECT b.userid, b.name 
FROM clients_b b
WHERE b.groupid = 123
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM clients_a a WHERE a.userid = b.userid AND a.name IS NOT NULL)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d025887bf499379c64cb5e47fd53d864).
Results:

| userid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Steve |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Paul |
| 4 | Jessy |

Comment: Thanks a lot  If I have an additional column `usertype` in both tables, but only want the usertype value from table `clients_b`, is there a simple way to add this to the query?

Comment: @Avatar no, this query picks full rows for clients_a or clients_b.